# Portal Site on WSS

Tags: wss

I have two questions...

Could I create a complete portal for Internet with WSS 3.0 or MOSS is necessary for that?

I wanted to know if it is possible to install WSS 3.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2003 is the only possibility for this version of Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question really depends on your definition of portal and how broad it is. It is possible to have an efficient intranet solution with WSS without full blown SharePoint. Microsoft offers a lot of [templates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx) too, for specific site types.

To your second question, yes you can install WSS 3.0 on 2008 R2, but you will need to apply the latest service packs.

Comment: I reffer to create CMS with WSS, I say end users modifing content in the web site.